# how to secure my browsing while using wifi

Tags: wireless, vpn

i use wifi with a vpn and sometimes tails and tor. i have no control over router settings but wifi is secure wpa/wpa2. the router is used by others in my apartment building also. can the sites i visit be observed by someone with router or isp access when i am using a vpn or tor. i'm not concerned with the vpn administrators knowing my browsing, only if others in my apartment complex can spy on me when i'm using a vpn or tor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're safe.

WPA/WPA2 just gives you an encrypted connection to the wireless router, it's unencrypted (by WPA/WPA2) after that.

A VPN sets up an encrypted tunnel between you and the VPN server. The other side of the VPN server is not encrypted. The VPN server can see your URLs.

TOR adds complicated routing, and conceals your IP address from the destination server. TOR encrypts your data from your computer all the way to the last TOR server before your destination.